# Cleaning flavor paths for different build types

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-flavors

I have about 8 flavours in my app, plus the default main flavour.
I want to have a different icon for each flavor but also a different icon for each build, eg debug, demo, release.

The folder structure, I believe, means I have to create mutliple folders as follows:

```
main
    -res
        -mipmap
flavor1
    -res
        -mipmap
flavor1Debug
    -res
        -mipmap
flavor1Demo
    -res
        -mipmap
flavor2
    -res
        -mipmap
flavor2Debug
    -res
        -mipmap
flavor2Demo
    -res
        -mipmap
```

But I want:

```
main
    -res
        -mipmap
flavor1
    -debug
        -res
            -mipmap
    -demo
        -res
            -mipmap
    -production
        -res
            -mipmap
flavor2
    -debug
        -res
            -mipmap
    -demo
        -res
            -mipmap
    -production
        -res
            -mipmap
```

This is so I have each flavors assets inside one folder per flavor, instead of creating multiple folders for each flavor + build.

Is this possible? I thought it worked like this as standard, but maybe I need to change my `sourceSets`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I achieved this by just using `sourceSets`, eg:

```
sourceSets {
        main { res.srcDirs += ['src/main/res'] }

        flavour1 {res.srcDirs += ['src/flavour1/main/res']}
        flavour1Dev { res.srcDirs += ['src/flavour1/dev/res'] }
        flavour1Demo { res.srcDirs += ['src/flavour1/demo/res'] }

        flavour2 { res.srcDirs += ['src/flavour2/main/res'] }
        flavour2Dev { res.srcDirs += ['src/flavour2/dev/res'] }
        flavour2Demo { res.srcDirs += ['src/flavour2/demo/res'] }
}
```